# Combining conditional probabilities using an unconditional copula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference, copula

First: just a bit of background on copulas.

Suppose we have a pair of continuous random variables $Y_1, Y_2$ with distribution functions $F_1(y_1)=P(Y_1\leq y_1)$ and $F_2(y_2)=P(Y_2\leq y_2)$.

Let their joint distribution function $F(y_1, y_2) = P(Y_1\leq y_1, Y_2\leq y_2)$ be described by the copula $C$ with $F(y_1, y_2) = C(F_1(y_1), F_2(y_2))$.

The joint density is then given by
$$
\begin{align}
f(y_1, y_2)
&=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y_1 \partial y_2}F(y_1, y_2)
\\
&=\underbrace{\left[\frac{\partial^2}{\partial u_1 \partial u_2}C(u_1, u_2)\right]_{u_1=F_1(y_1),\\ u_2=F_2(y_2)}}_{\equiv c(F_1(y_1), F_2(y_2))}\cdot f_1(y_1) f_2(y_2)\,,
\end{align}
$$
where $f_1,f_2$ are the marginal densities and $c$ is the copula density.

Now to the meat of the question. Let's introduce a third random variable $X$. Suppose we observe some $iid$ realizations of the vector $(X, Y_1)$ and of the vector $(X, Y_2)$ but crucially *never* the vector of all three, $(X, Y_1, Y_2)$.

Using these data, say we estimate some conditional densities, say $\hat f_1(y_1|x)$ and $\hat f_2(y_2|x)$. However, we have no direct information about the joint copula.

Suppose we want to estimate the joint conditional density $f(y_1, y_2|x)$. I would *conjecture* that the "best" we can do is something of the form
$$
\hat f(y_1, y_2|x) \propto c(F_1(y_1), F_2(y_2)) \hat f_1(y_1|x) \hat f_2(y_2|x)\,.
$$

This is of course an unnormalized density and does not in general have $\hat f_1(y_1|x)$ and $\hat f_2(y_2|x)$ as marginals. But it does feel like a "sensible" way of combining two conditional estimates given an unconditional copula.

Is there a more rigorous notion of "good" that this maximizes? Are there any estimators of this form in the existing literature?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your problem is completely under specified. Even if you know all pairwise dependencies, you know next to nothing about the triple dependency between $(X,Y_1,Y_2)$. It is the same as in the bivariate case: If you know two margins, what does it tell you about the bivariate copula? So you will have plenty of solutions consistent with the estimations. Why should your proposal of constant $(Y_1,Y_2)$ copula be the "best"? Another way to achieve uniqueness would be to use the 3-copula with maximal entropy, which is consistent with the 2-margins.

Comment: The max-entropy 3-copula is a really sensible approach here. I will definitely look into an approach like that.

I was definitely coming from a place of pure conjecture because I wasn't really sure where to start! Thanks for the feedback.